# Simple Jquery if/else like

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm missing something very simple here, I'm aware there's no if/else in JQuery but how can I do the same with this code?

```
 $("#dropDown").val("vegetables");
   $(newEl).css("background-color", "green");

$("#dropDown").val("meatFish");
   $(newEl).css("background-color", "red");
```

Basically, I want it to say, if the dropDown value is "vegetables" then apply that css value, if it's "meatFish" then apply that other css.

Comment: `if($("#dropDown").val() == "vegetables"){...}else{...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `if else` from JavaScript and `val()` from jQuery:

```
if($("#dropDown").val() == "vegetables") {
  $(newEl).css("background-color", "green");
} else if ($("#dropDown").val() == "meatFish") {
  $(newEl).css("background-color", "red");
}
```

Comment: That works just perfect, thank you, will accept when it let me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this following code.

```js
$(document).on('ready change', function() {
  $('span').css('color', $('#veg').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="veg">
  <option value="green" selected="selected">1</option>
  <option value="blue">2</option>
</select>
<span>New element</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var obj = {"vegetables":"green","meatFish":"red"}
var val = $("#dropDown").val();
 $(newEl).css("background-color", obj[val]);
```

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  var obj = {
    "vegetables": "green",
    "meatFish": "red"
  }
  var val = $(this).val();
  $('span').css("background-color", obj[val]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="vegetables">vegetables</option>
  <option value="meatFish">meatFish</option>
</select>
<span>New element</span>
```